# jquery ajax call returning more than a single word

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I'm using the following code to use the return from a php

```
if (isset($_POST['P_Id'])) {
    if (!isset($_SESSION['carted_products'])) {
        $_SESSION['carted_products'] = array();
    }//end if not set products array in session

    if (!in_array($_POST['P_Id'], $_SESSION['carted_products'])) {
        array_push($_SESSION['carted_products'], $_POST['P_Id']);
        echo "success";
    }//end if not in array
    else {
        echo "already_added";
    }
}//end if not set post value
else {
    echo "fail";
}//end else
```

now in the jquery part of the calling page. I use

```
$.post(
    "add_to_cart.php",
    {P_Id:"<?php echo $row['P_Id'] ?>"},
    function(responseText){
        //if(responseText === "success"){
        //things to do on success
    }
```

but the if won't return true.

now when i check index of "already_added" in responseText it returns 6..

why is this happening.

Comment: can you try putting `exit();` or `return;` right after your `echo` statements?

Answer (score 0):

There is probably white spaces in your response, try trimming it.

```
if($.trim(responseText) === "success"){
```

Answer (score 0):

In the php try echo '0' and so on.
In the JS AJAX on success, do
....

```
function(response) {
  if(response == 0) { //fail }
  if(response == 1) { //success }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably echoing out some other text on the php side (whitespace before the `<?php`. To get at what is really happening you should use a client side console like firebug or the chrome dev tool and do a `console.log(responseText);` before the if in your `.$post` success callback

Answer (score 0):

Well, just a quick glance an I see you're not closing your jquery post and there's no semicolon after your echo.

```
$.post("add_to_cart.php",{P_Id:"<?php echo $row['P_Id']; ?>"},function(responseText){
    if(responseText === "success"){
        //things to do on success
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Personally I highly recommended to transfer data as JOSN format. I think that will be more secure and error free.